# How to create a method to add or multiply two fractions in a fraction class?

Tags: c++, class, oop

Following is the code I wrote. It does not show any error but also no output comes out.
The add and multiply methods should be able to store the sum and products into the fraction object and the print() method must be able to print out the answers. But its not happening in the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Fraction {
    private:
    int num;
    int den;

    public:
    Fraction(int a, int b) {
        num = a;
        den = b;
    }

    void simplify() {
        int gcd = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<=min(num, den); i++) {
            if(num%i==0 && den%i==0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }
    }

    void print() {
        cout<<num<<"/"<<den<<endl;
    }

    void add(Fraction const &f2) {
        int lcm = den * f2.den;
        int x = lcm/den;
        int y = lcm/f2.den;

        int n = x*num + (y*f2.num);

        num = n;
        den = lcm;

        simplify();
    }

    void multiply(Fraction const &f2) {
        num = num*f2.num;
        den = den*f2.den;

        simplify();
    }
};



int main() {

    Fraction f1(2,3);
    Fraction f2(3,5);

    //f1.print();
    //f2.print();

    f1.add(f2);

    f1.print();
    f2.print();

    f1.multiply(f2);

    f1.print();
    f2.print();
    return 0;

}
```

Can someone help me modify my code for it to start working or point out the mistakes I made?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: It seems that `simplify()` has no observable effect.

Comment: The *divide by zero* in `simplify()` is likely causing problems.

Comment: This is c++, we don't write add or multiply functions. We have operators.

Comment: In `simplify` you really should use a better gcd algorithm, like `std::gcd`

Comment: Aside from dividing by zero, your `simplify()` function has no effect.  It puts values in a local variable `gcd`, and then the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

The `simplify()` function is not right. Since you are using `num % i` and `den % i`, i should start with '1' and not '0'.

Comment: Please consider adding what's pointed out in [Goswin von Brederlow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72687079/how-to-create-a-method-to-add-or-multiply-two-fractions-in-a-fraction-class#comment128393417_72687079) and [Drew Dorman's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72687079/how-to-create-a-method-to-add-or-multiply-two-fractions-in-a-fraction-class#comment128403142_72687079) comments, too.